# How to "contact" Facebook page "fans"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a Facebook page for my website.

I wish to contact the people who became fans of my page.  I know that sending a message is not a possibility (only for Facebook groups), but what **can** be done to contact them?

In other words, what feature of the page connects to what information stream in the "fan" Facebook profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post on the page. That should feed into every fan's homefeed (unless they've "Liked" your page but have "Unfollowed" your updates).

Comment: Thanks - is that the only option ?

Answer (score 4):

You can send email updates to all your fans by clicking on edit page under the profile picture then under promote your page click send an update.

[image] [image]

Comment: The send update goes to the "update" page, which is like the massage box, just more dark :)   Thanks.

Comment: That update page it goes to send an email to all your fans.  I just tested it on my page.

Comment: I was wondering if that was the only option really :)

Comment: Either the location has changed or it's different for different pages. In my page you have to click edit page, then marketing, then send an update.

Comment: @Daphna, I have noticed the same thing but it looks like none of my fans got the update I sent them